# Best method to validate a three alphanumeric string against a list of available numbers and letters

Tags: jquery, match

I'm trying to validate an input field and force the user to retype it if its bad. 
The input will always be one number 1 to 22 and one character A to F. My code looks like below, the issue is everything entered is being report 'Not Good'. Why?

```
function checkFD() {
    var str = $("#fieldday").val().trim().toUpperCase();
    var letterNumber = /^[1-22A-F]+$/;
        if (str.match(letterNumber)) {
            alert("its good");
            checkIn();
            return true;
        } else { 
            alert("not good"); 
            return false; 
        }
}
```

Comment: Think you want `.test()` not `.match()`.

Comment: str.test() is NOT a function and throws an error.

Comment: Yes, it would be `letterNumber.test(str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, it is looking for an input which is comprised of some number of characters in the set `1,2,A,B,C,D,E,F`. What you want is to check that the first part is a number in the range `1-22` and that is followed by a character in the range `A-F`. This should work:

```
var letterNumber = /^(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])[A-F]$/;
```

Note since you are only checking for a match, you should use `letterNumber.test(str)` rather than `str.match(letterNumber)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function checkIn() {
    // Do the needful
  }

  function checkFD() {
    var str = $(this).val().trim();
    var regex = /^(?:[1-9]|1\d|2[0-2])[A-F]$/i;
    var valid = regex.test(str);
    if (valid) {
      alert("its good");
      $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
      checkIn();
    } else {
      alert("not good");
    }
    return valid;
  }

  $("#code").change(checkFD);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="code" />
```

You can enter `1A` up to `22F` and it reports Good. If you enter `23AF`, it reports Bad.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test